# Node.js - TypeError: Cannot read property 'exec' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I follow a tutorial on youtube and I made this code but it did not work with me while it worked with him!

```
router.post('/signup', (req,res) => {
User.findOne({ email: req.body.email })
console.log('===> 1')
.exec((error, user) => {
    console.log('===> 2')
    if(user) return res.status(400).json({
        message: 'User already registered!'
    });
    const { firstName, lastName, email, password } = req.body;
    const _user = new User({ firstName, lastName, email, password, username: Math.random().toString() });
    _user.save((error, data) => {
        if(error){
            return res.status(400).json({
                message: 'Something went wrong!'
            });
        }
        if(data){
            return res.status(201).json({
                user: data
            })
        }
    });
});});
```

it show this message(Cannot read property 'exec' of undefined)?

Comment: Move your first console.log line before `User.findOne`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the `exec()` function on top of the `console.log()` function like: `console.log().exec()` which of course does not exists. Please check your tutorial again and make sure you're not missing a piece of code that needs to run before you call `exec()`.

Comment: Yes, it worked. thank you.
Actually, me who writes the console.log() to check errors, but unfortunately console.log() itself became the problem :)